# How do I fix the APT error "The following packages have unmet dependencies"?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation

I bought a System76 laptop. However, every time I try to install something, I get this error (or something similar):

```
mike@mike-Lemur:~$ sudo apt-get install curl
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
curl is already the newest version (7.47.0-1ubuntu2.2). 
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these: 
The following packages have unmet dependencies: 
 libgcc1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.2.4) but it is not going to be installed 
 libgcrypt20:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.15) but it is not going to be installed 
 libgpg-error0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.15) but it is not going to be installed 
 liblzma5:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed 
 libpcre3:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed 
 libselinux1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.8) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: The error suggests `Try 'apt-get -f install'` Have you tried that yet ?

Comment: What did you install prior to this? You shouldn't see these dependencies for 32-bit packages in a standard 64-bit install.

Comment: Did you run sudo apt-get update first?

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy I did, and it said apt-get -f install
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?

Comment: @chaskes nothing that I'm aware of. I tried to install Wine right off the bat, and it gave me the error-

Comment: @MikeWilliams you need `sudo`, that's why it says permission denied

Comment: Hard to know. I suggest you run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -f install && sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Answer (score 2):

Run this command on your system:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -f install && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: Emma, have a look [here](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/17013/what-should-we-do-with-answers-that-include-contact-details-for-relevant-support), please?